# Is the result of a boolean operation 1 or 0 in C?

Tags: c, boolean

Is the result of a boolean operation guaranteed to be 1 or 0?

I'm programming a microcontroller and need to set a pin to 1 or 0, and was wondering if I can shorten the code from this:

```
isRunning = isStarted && !isSleeping;
_PBH0 = isRunning ? 1 : 0;
```

to this:

```
isRunning = isStarted && !isSleeping;
_PBH0 = isRunning;
```

Comment: False is 0 and true is any non-zero integer.

Comment: Yes.  It's guaranteed.  By *definition*.

Comment: @devnull What do you mean? Aren't all answers about the standard "by definition"? (or did I miss a pun?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the result of `&&` operator (or any of the logical operators) is an `int` that has a value of either `1` or `0`.

> #### C11 §6.5.13 Logical AND operator
>
> The `&&` operator shall yield `1` if both of its operands compare unequal to `0`; otherwise, it yields `0`. The result has type `int`.

Comment: Thanks. Do `||` and `!` also return either 1 or 0?

Comment: @Andreas Yes, that's what I mean by *any of the logical operators*.

Answer (score 2):

Infact, you can reduce to`_PHB0 = (isStarted && !isSleeping);`